# Как сделать proxy в nginx для изображений с внешнего сайта?

Tags: nginx, pagespeed-insights

Здравствуйте!
Провожу оптимизацию сайта по рекомендациям из pagespeed. Есть задачка по "Используйте кеш браузера". Для локальных файлов сделал, но у меня есть внешние ресурсы и я нашел интересную тему с яндекс метрикой.

```
location = /metrika.js {
  expires 30d;
  proxy_pass https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js;
  proxy_set_header Host mc.yandex.ru;
}
```

Но помимо яндекса есть еще много изображений со стороннего ресурса. Как сделать универсальное правило?

Например:

Ссылка на изображение от поставщика:
https://external.ru/catalog/img1.jpg

А я хочу, чтобы эта ссылку у меня открывалась как:
https://mysite.ru/catalog/img1.jpg

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Нужно воспользоваться переменными и захватом нужной части uri регуляркой в location

```
location ~* ^/catalog/(.*)$ {
     proxy_pass $scheme://external.ru/catalog/$1;
     proxy_set_header Host      $host:$server_port;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Ещё момент: обратите внимаени на куки. они могут передаваться внешему сайту.

Comment: К сожалению не работает(((

Comment: честно не проверял, но смотрите в этом направлении. может что поправить нужно. может схема не та. надо смотреть на конкретном примере

Comment: Ответ в моем вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ:

```
location ^~ /catalog { 
expires 30d;
proxy_pass https://external.ru
```